# Where option -> New > Vector Asset on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, svg

I would like to add an SVG image to the Res folder. Right-click to option in the res -> add new file... there is no Asset Vector... Why? What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this path to find New Vector Asset

`app->res->drawable`. right click on `drawable` then `New->Vector Asset`

For reference follow below image:

[image]

I hope its work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If at all, all the above are not working - 
Here's what we can do,
**that helped me getting the** `Image Asset` & `Vector Asset` successfully-

Go to `File > Open` then open the `android` directory..

> See here --> [how to open and proceed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgMpm.png)

And then open in `NEW WINDOW` as shown below -

> See here --> [where to open the `android` in new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jfUy.png)

In the new Window, where the `android` directory is opened, you would get the options **Successfully** -

> Finally click here --> [You will get the options for `Image Asset` & `Vector Asset`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKp7p.png)

Comment: That's kind of ironic isn't it ? I asked 2 years, 7 months ago!

Answer (score 0):

For first step you have to build the project correctly.

as https://developer.android.com/studio/build

The problem sue on bottom bar in your android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try using different version of Android (before 4.4) for "Vector Assert" to appear in a "New" context menu. [Path to Vector Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHhtX.png)