# Unable to add an Android asset in Android Studio. Where did the option go?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

### Context

I am working on a Flutter application and have done all my development in VS Code (my preferred editor). I'm at a point where I need to add [vector assets](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#about) to my project.

### Problem

I navigate to the folder in Android Studio `my_app/android/app/src/main/res/` or `my_app/android/app/src/main/res/drawable` and then *right-click*. I look for the option in the context menu: **New > Vector Asset**, but it's not there (*see image below*). This happens at both of the said paths.

### What I've tried

- I've tried creating a new asset folder at `my_app/android/app/res/drawable` and the option still doesn't not appear in the context menu.
- I've looked at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873164/where-option-new-vector-asset-on-android-studio), but the accepted solution didn't work (what I tried above). The next suggested solution is to downgrade Android Studio.
- I've tried opening just the `android` directory in Android Studio and that didn't work either.

### My Questions

1. Where did the option go?
2. How do I add a vector asset with having to downgrade Android Studio versions?

[image: No New > Vector Asset here]

Answer (score 3):

They spruced it up, you use the `Resource Manager` now - if the tab isn't on the top left of the screen then it's in the `Tools` menu. Once that's open, press the `+` icon in the top left and you can add a `Vector Asset`. You can import one, or there's a `Clip Art` option with built-in icons you can choose from.

edit- that might actually be what you're talking about, and I have the `New > Vector Asset` option if I right click `drawable` or `res`, in both the `Android` and `Project` views. Maybe try a `Clean` and `Rebuild` in the `Build` menu, or `Invalidate caches/restart` in `File` to give it a kick

Comment: Hey this didn't exactly work, but it led me forward. I ran `Invalidate caches/restart` and a mesasge in the event log came up: `Frameworks Detected` > `Android framework is detected.`. I followed the default prompts to configure it and now have the options: `New` > `Android Resource File`, `New` > `Android Resource Directory`, and `New` > `Sample Data Directory`. But none lead me to the `Vector Asset` option.

Comment: I did open the `Resource Manager` panel, but only says `Waiting for build to finish...`. I'm going to look into this as well. (PS Thank you!)

Comment: Yeah it was suspicious that none of your menu items looked Android-related at all! It does seem like it's not recognised that it's an Android project, but I don't really know a lot about this side of things. A gradle sync might help (elephant icon on the toolbar) but honestly I'm just guessing. Hope you get it sorted out though!

Answer (score 0):

Given link is show you, how to add vector asset in android studio.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

1. You need to add setting in build.gradle (app) file.

   android {

   defaultConfig {
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

   }

   }

   dependencies {

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
   ```

   }
2. steps to add vector asset in res folder:
   In Android Studio, open an Android app project.
   In the Project window, select the Android view.
   Right-click the res folder and select New > Vector Asset.
   Some other project views and folders have this menu item as well.
   If a Need Newer Android Plugin for Gradle dialog appears instead, correct your Gradle version as follows:
   Select File > Project Structure.
   In the Project Structure dialog, select Project.
   In the Android Plugin Version field, change the Android Plugin for Gradle version to 1.5.0 or higher, and click OK.
   Gradle syncs the project.
   In the Android view of the Project window, right-click the res folder and select New > Vector Asset.
   Vector Asset Studio appears.

Answer (score 0):

Open resource manager from Tools:
[image]

From there press Import Drawables

[image]

Now you can select a svg file you want to import and name it etc.